# How to set the id of a div as cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have got a task to highlight the selected menu while refreshing the page. For that I want to use cookie.
Html code is

```
<div class="menuBar">
            <div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top">
             <span><a href="#" onclick="Home()" id="home">Home</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top">
             <span><a href="#" onclick="NewTransaction()" id="newtransaction">New Transaction</a></span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Javascript file is

```
function Home() {
            window.location.href = "../../home/welcome";
        }
        function NewTransaction() {
            window.location.href = "../../EnergyCatagory/index";
        }
```

But I have a code to set the menu as selected.But its not a good way.How can I pass the value of the selected menu to the page while refreshing?
this is the code for highlighting the menu

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var currentUrl = window.location.href;
                if (currentUrl.indexOf("home/welcome") !== -1) {
                    $("#home").parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
                }
                else if (currentUrl.indexOf("EnergyCatagory/index") !== -1) {
                    $("#newtransaction").parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
                }
                else if (currentUrl.indexOf("portfolio/Index") !== -1) {
                    $("#portfolio").parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
                }
            });
```

Comment: @MatthewAgustin, can any code be "non semantic"? For me the answer is no. A mountain is non semantic, as is a laundry basket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
function goToLocation(sLocation, id) {
   $.cookie("activediv", id);
   window.location.href = sLocation;
}
```

in html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToLocation('../../home/welcome', 'home')" id="home">Home</a>
```

in jQuery ready:

```
$('#' + $.cookie("activediv")).parent().parent().addClass('menuHeaderActive');
```

Comment: @ChrisMoutray- Here I got an error like this  TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var a=($.cookie("activediv")); But I have the cookie plugin <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @victor-Here I got an error like this TypeError: $.cookie is not a function [Break On This Error] var a=($.cookie("activediv")); But I have the cookie plugin <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Link about cookie with jQuery is on comment below. I am only use your information and information about cookie to compile some result.

Comment: @Chris Moutray thank you to correct my answer - order in function is very important.

Answer (score 4):

Give id for every menu item.

Then in the onclick() function of menu item set that id as cookie.

Set cookie

```
$.cookie("selectedId", $(this).attr('id'));
```

In document.ready function add selected class to the element with id obtained from cookie

Answer (score 1):

Try to set cookises using jQuery as:

```
$.cookie("name", "value");
```

More you can read here:[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery#)

Comment: I know this.But how to implement this on my proect